# apache/mod_rewrite returns an existing files from a defined folder if it exists else a default one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to write a *.htaccess* for my apache website, with this kind of rules :

For a client which asks (HTTP GET) this url :

```
http://myserver/img123.jpg
```

If the file **img123.jpg** exists in my folder **/var/images/**, the server returns it.
If it doesn't exist, it returns the default file which is in the root directory : **/imgdefault.jpg**

The following rule works if the file exists in the root directory (as the default one), but I'd like to check it in another absolute folder.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^img.*\.jpg$ /imgdefault.jpg
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible .... but I don't know rewritecond rules enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct path like:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/images/$0 -s
RewriteRule ^img.*\.jpg$ var/images/$0
```